# Python typing, named tuple missing default values when calling _asdict()

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-typing

I have this class

```
from typing import Tuple, NamedTuple, cast, List, Dict
class PdfRequestDownloadData(NamedTuple):
  workspace_id: int
  since: str
  until: str
  project_ids: List[int]
  date_format = "YYYY-MM-DD"
  duration_format = "improved"
  hide_amounts = True
  hide_rates = True
  order_by = "title"
  order_dir = "asc"
  sub_grouping = "time_entries"
```

notice, the bottom part are the defaults, e.g. the ones with =

I call:

```
x = PdfRequestDownloadData(project_ids=[projectid], workspace_id=workspaceid,since=fromdate, until=todate)

print(x._asdict())
```

output:

```
OrderedDict([('workspace_id', 98333), ('since', '2019-08-01'), ('until', '2019-08-31'), ('project_ids', [123334])])
```

where did all the defaults go? what would be a good solution?

Comment: Those aren't default values, they're class variables. Which is why they're missing, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the type annotations for the "default values" as such they are class attributes. if you give them a type they will be instance attributes:

```
class C:
    required: int
    optional: int = 5
```

[typing.NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple)